# JPA query form to get Explain Plan (Oracle)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa

I want to have a method that would receive a JPA Query and then return the explain plan result for that query. It gives me an error saying that the table or view does not exist. Which makes sense since the entity class name is different than the table name.

Here is the query to get the explain plan (works fine when the query is a native query)

```
String explainQuery = String.format("EXPLAIN PLAN SET STATEMENT_ID = '%s' INTO PLAN_TABLE
FOR %s",statementId, query.replaceFirst(";?\\z", ""));
```

Now if the query is

```
"Select * from myTable"
```

I would have my expected result. but if I change it to

```
"Select mtl from myTableEntity mtl"
```

I would get an error.
Can you help me with this?
Thanks

Comment: The second query is not a valid SQL statement (unless `myTableEntity` happens to have a column `mtl`).  The proper SQL to get all the rows from a table using an alias is `select mtl.* from myTableEntity mtl`.

Comment: I think not! I execute this query and it works fine, the result is basically the same as executing select * from mytable. but when I use it as the query to get the explain plan, then I face error

Comment: The second query isn't valid SQL.  Here's a SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/33795 that shows the two versions that work (`SELECT *` and `SELECT d.*`) and the one that fails (`SELECT d`).

Comment: Second query is a JPA query, myTableEntity is an entity mapped to myTable (in java code). I do not need to lie, I am executing my current query and I am receiving correct results! The resolution to my question is not what you are pointing at.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you're lying.  `explain plan` has no idea how to convert a valid JPA query into a valid SQL query, it can only deal with valid SQL queries.  If the first query works and the second query doesn't, the fact that one is a valid SQL statement and the other is not would seem to be material.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense but I am assuring you that the second query (when executed in another class created for executing JPA select statements) works fine, so I assume the query is valid.